# How do I completely destroy a socket.io connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm creating a browser chat from Socket.io and Node.js. Everything has been running smoothly, but I appear to be having a problem with disconnecting sockets. When I run `socket.disconnet();`, the server runs the `socket.on("disconnect",` event, but it doesn't actually remove the socket from internal listeners.

When I run `socket.disconnect();` on a socket, the socket no longer recieves any new messages, but when the "disconnected" user sends a message, the server receives and sends it back to all clients. I want to create a proper `/kick` command but it's difficult when I have to restructure all of my code just to accomidate for a simple function.

Commands like `socket.connection.destroy();`, `socket.end();`, and `socket.transport.destroy();` are invalid and undefined. Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been working on this problem for days and I haven't found any answer other than to set a `shutup` boolean to the socket and tell the message event to ignore specific sockets. Is this the best way? What happens if the user starts editing javascript code and I need a way from receiving other events from a client?

Comment: node version? socket.io version? Looking at the source https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/socket.js#L290 `socket.disconnect()` looks right.

Comment: As I have said, "When I run socket.disconnect(); on a socket, the socket no longer recieves any new messages, but when the "disconnected" user sends a message, the server receives and sends it back to all clients"

Comment: "no longer receives any new messages" seems to contradict "the server receives and sends it back".

Comment: sends it back to other clients

Comment: but the kicked client doesn't get the messages. Logging shows that socket.io doesn't discard any transport for the socket.

Comment: If it's really behaving that way it's a bug in socket.io

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you think the close v1.0 update might fix this?

Comment: Yes, you should also check the issues and post your issue there if you can't find it.

Comment: Are you sure that the client is not reconnecting automatically? I've used `socket.disconnect()` without problems.

Comment: I disabled reconnecting on the client side. There's no reason for the client to reconnect, and socket.io's logs show that the socket stays connected, but it only says "booting client."

Comment: After 60 seconds, the client can still send messages, but cannot see them. It uses the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can see if the socket is connected or not. If socket is connected you can emit the data and vice versa. :)
Hope it helps..!

```
YourProject.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){     
  setInterval(function(){   
    if(!socket.disconnected){
      socket.emit('entrance',{message:'Hey Bro'}); 
    }      
  },10000);        
});
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to interrupt thread ? That should end all I/O operations with an Exception.

Comment: Why would I wanted to end all I/O operations? I want to be as efficient as possible.